# Can I send 2FA token via email using Twilio's authy api?

Tags: twilio, authy

I want to send 2-Factor Authentication token via email using Twilio's Authy api. I know Authy api offering Push Authentication, Soft token, SMS/Voice but is it also possible to send token via email?
If so, then can I register the user at authy without providing phone number and country code but just will give email address? Actually I only need to send token via email not over the phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authy adds support for user authentication via email 
https://www.twilio.com/changelog/authy-adds-support-user-authentication-email

Comment: Thanks Alan. Yes, I did the email integrations and it is working on fine. But problem is  here that we need to register the user at Authy before deliver the token via email. And during registration, api end point required phone number, country code and email as required field. So, if user want to enable 2FA and chose Email channel then why the user will provide phone number as well. Means, can I register the user at Authy by only email?

Comment: Maybe Twilio Verify would work better, since it does have the same requirement? https://www.twilio.com/changelog/verify-adds-support-user-verification-email